# Simplify a JQuery code

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

I have many popovers in my page ([JSBin](https://jsbin.com/qeyajihece/edit?html,output)), each `data-toggle` is linked to a html div. It is now realized by the following script:

```
<script>
    $('[data-toggle="popover0"]').popover({
    html: true,
    content: function() {
    return $("#popover0-html").html()
    }});

    $('[data-toggle="popover1"]').popover({
    html: true,
    content: function() {
    return $("#popover1-html").html()
    }});    

    $('[data-toggle="popover2"]').popover({
    html: true,
    content: function() {
    return $("#popover2-html").html()
    }});
</script>
```

I would like to simply the above code by saying "for all data-toggle with an ID, we return the html whose id is `ID` + `-html`". Does anyone know how to realize this?

Comment: Use `for`. `for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    $('[data-toggle="popover' + i + '"]').popover({
        html: true,
        content: function() {
            return $("#popover" + i + "-html").html();
        }
    });
}`

Comment: I see... but what if I don't know the number of popovers (i.e., `3` here). I just want to say "for all the popovers", or "for all the popovers whose id starts with the string `popover`"...

Comment: `$('[data-toggle^="popover"]').length`

Comment: @Tushar - I suspect the `content` function will be executed later, at which point `i` will be 3...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is:

```
$('[data-toggle]').popover({
   html: true,
   content: function() {
      var id = "#" + this.getAttribute('data-toggle') + "-html";
      return $(id).html();
   }
});
```

The above script uses value of the `data-toggle` attribute for selecting the target element. It works for 1 or many elements.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
    for (var i=0;i<3;i++) {
       var selector = '[data-toggle="popover'+ i +'"]';
       var popover = '#popover' + i +'-html';
       $(selector ).popover({
        html: true,
        content: function() {
        return $(popover ).html()
       }});
    }
</script>
```